# Ejecutar función cuando se hace clic en un elemento existente o insertado dinámicamente en el DOM con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, eventos, dom

Tengo una especie de formulario donde se añaden preguntas y respuestas para un test, todas mis funciones realizan su tarea según mis expectativas menos una de ella la cual es llamada varias veces cada vez que se presiona un botón (fué la solución que encontré para que cuando se creen elementos nuevos en el DOM volver a recorrer los nuevos elementos)

La función agrega nuevas posibles respuestas al DOM pero el problema que tengo es que a medida que se van creando nuevos campos de preguntas los elementos que van quedando atrás se va repitiendo la función más de la cuenta. Por ejemplo, tengo 3 campos de preguntas, si añado 1 nueva respuesta al último campo se inserta una respuesta (como debe ser) pero en el segundo se inserta 2 veces la respuesta y en el primero 3 veces, supongo que esto tiene que ver con el hecho de que llamo a la función que comprueba el clic en los diferentes elementos cada vez que se inserta un nuevo campo de pregunta.

Curiosamente otras funciones que llamo cada vez que se crea un nuevo campo de preguntas no ejecutan su funcionalidad más veces de lo esperado, solamente me ocurre con la función para agregar respuestas. Si no me habéis entendido preguntadme.

Comparto código a continuación:

**HTML y PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin/tests/crearTest.css">
</head>

<body>

    <main class="test">
        <div class="contenedor">

            <div class="contenedor__nombre">
                <p>Nombre del Test</p>
                <input type="text" name="nombreTest" id="nombreTest" class="inputTexto">
            </div>

            <div class="contenedor__temarioPerteneciente">

                <p>Seleccione Temario al que Pertenece</p>
                <select name="temarioPerteneciente" id="temarioPerteneciente">
                    <option value="">Ninguna Opción Seleccionada</option>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultarTemarios))
                    {
                        $id = $row['id_temario'];
                        $nombre = $row['nombre_temario'];

                        echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $nombre . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>

            </div>


        </div>

    </main>

    <div id="contenedorVistasPrevias">

        <div class="vistaPrevia" id="vistaPrevia-1" numvistaprevia="1">

            <div class="vistaPrevia__pregunta">
                <p>Nombre de la Pregunta</p>
                <input type="text" name="" id="nombrePregunta-1" class="inputTexto textoPregunta">

                <p>Añadir Respuesta</p>
                <input type="text" name="" id="añadirRespuesta-1" class="inputTexto textoRespuesta">
                <button class="vistaPrevia__pregunta__boton botonDesactivado btnAñadir" id="btnAñadirRespuesta-1">Añadir</button>
                <p>Escoja la respuesta correcta</p>
            </div>

            <div class="vistaPrevia__respuestas">
                <div class="vistaPrevia__respuestas__radio radioRespuestas" id="vistaPreviaRespuestasRadio-1">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>



    <div class="contenedorEnviarTest">
        <button class="agregarPregunta botonDesactivado" id="btnAgregarPregunta">Agregar Pregunta</button>
    </div>

    <div class="contenedorEnviarTest">
        <button class="enviarTest botonDesactivado" id="btnEnviarTest">Enviar Test</button>
    </div>

    <script src="/js/admin/test/peticionTest.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
/*=============================================
=         Validar Agregar Pregunta            =
=============================================*/

let nombreTest = document.getElementById("nombreTest");
let select = document.getElementById("temarioPerteneciente");
const btnAgregarPregunta = document.getElementById("btnAgregarPregunta");

let valueSelect = "";

if (nombreTest.textContent === "") {
    btnAgregarPregunta.disabled = true;
}

select.addEventListener("change", () => {
    let opcionSeleccionada = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    let idTemarioSeleccionado = opcionSeleccionada.value;
    valueSelect = idTemarioSeleccionado;

    // idTemarioCorrespondiente.value = idTemarioSeleccionado;

    console.log(idTemarioSeleccionado);

    if (nombreTest.value !== "" && valueSelect !== "") {
        btnAgregarPregunta.disabled = false;
        btnAgregarPregunta.classList.remove("botonDesactivado");
    } else {
        btnAgregarPregunta.disabled = true;
        btnAgregarPregunta.classList.add("botonDesactivado");
    }
    validarTestCompleto();
});

nombreTest.onkeyup = () => {
    if (nombreTest.value !== "" && valueSelect !== "") {
        btnAgregarPregunta.disabled = false;
        btnAgregarPregunta.classList.remove("botonDesactivado");
    } else {
        btnAgregarPregunta.disabled = true;
        btnAgregarPregunta.classList.add("botonDesactivado");
    }
    validarTestCompleto();
};

/*============  End of Validar Agregar Pregunta  =============*/

/*=============================================
=          Validar Añadir Respuesta           =
=============================================*/

validarAñadirRespuesta = () => {
    let añadirRespuesta = document.querySelectorAll(".textoRespuesta");
    let nombrePregunta = document.querySelectorAll(".textoPregunta");
    let btnAñadir = document.querySelectorAll(".btnAñadir");

    añadirRespuesta.forEach((elementoActual, indice) => {
        elementoActual.onkeyup = function () {
            if (
                añadirRespuesta[indice].value !== "" &&
                nombrePregunta[indice].value !== ""
            ) {
                btnAñadir[indice].disabled = false;
                btnAñadir[indice].classList.remove("botonDesactivado");
            } else {
                btnAñadir[indice].disabled = true;
                btnAñadir[indice].classList.add("botonDesactivado");
            }
            validarTestCompleto();
        };
    });

    nombrePregunta.forEach((elementoActual, indice) => {
        elementoActual.onkeyup = function () {
            if (
                añadirRespuesta[indice].value !== "" &&
                nombrePregunta[indice].value !== ""
            ) {
                btnAñadir[indice].disabled = false;
                btnAñadir[indice].classList.remove("botonDesactivado");
            } else {
                btnAñadir[indice].disabled = true;
                btnAñadir[indice].classList.add("botonDesactivado");
            }
            validarTestCompleto();
        };
    });
};

validarAñadirRespuesta();

/*============  End of Validar Añadir Respuesta  =============*/

/*=============================================
=               Añadir Respuesta              =
=============================================*/
let numRadioLabel = 1;

añadiendoRespuesta = (indice) => {
    let añadirRespuesta = document.querySelectorAll(".textoRespuesta");
    let radioRespuestas = document.querySelectorAll(".radioRespuestas");

    let radioRespuesta = `
            <div class="vistaPrevia__respuestas__radio__elemento" numrespuesta="${numRadioLabel}">
                <div class="vistaPrevia__respuestas__radio__elemento__contenedor">
                    <div class="radio-block">
                        <div class="radio-content">
                            <input id="radio${numRadioLabel}" type="radio" name="radio-${
        indice + 1
    }" class="radio"/>
                            <label for="radio${numRadioLabel}" class="respuesta"><span></span></label>
                            <p class="respuesta">${
                                añadirRespuesta[indice].value
                            }</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="eliminarRespuesta">
                    <button class="eliminarRespuesta__botón" numrespuesta="${numRadioLabel}" >Eliminar</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            `;

    radioRespuestas[indice].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", radioRespuesta);

    numRadioLabel++;
    botonesRadio();
    botonesEliminarRespuesta();
    console.log("añadiendi");
};

añadirRespuesta = () => {
    btnAñadirRespuesta = document.querySelectorAll(".btnAñadir");

    btnAñadirRespuesta.forEach((botonActual, indice) => {
        botonActual.addEventListener("click", () => {
            añadiendoRespuesta(indice);
        });
    });
};

añadirRespuesta();
/*============  End of Añadir Respuesta  =============*/

/*=============================================
=              Agregar Pregunta               =
=============================================*/

var numID = 2;

btnAgregarPregunta.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let contenedorVistasPrevias = document.getElementById(
        "contenedorVistasPrevias"
    );

    let nuevaPregunta = `

<div class="vistaPrevia" id="vistaPrevia-${numID}" numvistaprevia="${numID}">

    <div class="vistaPrevia__pregunta">
        <p>Nombre de la Pregunta</p>
        <input type="text" name="" id="nombrePregunta-${numID}" class="inputTexto textoPregunta">

        <p>Añadir Respuesta</p>
        <input type="text" name="" id="añadirRespuesta-${numID}" class="inputTexto textoRespuesta">
        <button class="vistaPrevia__pregunta__boton botonDesactivado btnAñadir" id="btnAñadirRespuesta-1">Añadir</button>
        <p>Escoja la respuesta correcta</p>
    </div>

    <div class="vistaPrevia__respuestas">
        <div class="vistaPrevia__respuestas__radio radioRespuestas" id="vistaPreviaRespuestasRadio-${numID}">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="eliminarPregunta">
        <button class="eliminarPregunta__botón" numvistaprevia="${numID}">Eliminar Pregunta</button>
    </div>

</div>

`;
    contenedorVistasPrevias.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", nuevaPregunta);

    numID++;

    validarAñadirRespuesta();
    añadirRespuesta();
    validarTestCompleto();
    botonesEliminarPregunta();
});

/*============  End of Agregar Pregunta  =============*/

/*=============================================
=                 Validar Test                =
=============================================*/

let botonAgregarPregunta = document.getElementById("btnAgregarPregunta");
const btnEnviarTest = document.getElementById("btnEnviarTest");

validarAgregarPregunta = () => {
    if (botonAgregarPregunta.classList.contains("botonDesactivado")) {
        botonAgregarPreguntaValido--;
    } else {
        botonAgregarPreguntaValido++;
    }
};

validarTestCompleto = () => {
    let botonesRadio = document.querySelectorAll(".radio");
    let botonesAñadir = document.querySelectorAll(".btnAñadir");

    botonesRadioActivos = 0;
    botonesAñadirValidos = 0;
    botonAgregarPreguntaValido = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < botonesRadio.length; i++) {
        if (botonesRadio[i].checked === true) {
            botonesRadioActivos++;
        } else {
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < botonesAñadir.length; i++) {
        if (botonesAñadir[i].classList.contains("botonDesactivado")) {
            botonesAñadirValidos--;
        } else {
            botonesAñadirValidos++;
        }
    }

    validarAgregarPregunta();

    if (
        botonesRadioActivos === numID - 1 &&
        botonesAñadirValidos === numID - 1 &&
        botonAgregarPreguntaValido > 0
    ) {
        btnEnviarTest.classList.remove("botonDesactivado");
        btnEnviarTest.disabled = false;
    } else {
        btnEnviarTest.classList.add("botonDesactivado");
        btnEnviarTest.disabled = true;
    }
};

botonesRadio = () => {
    let botonesRadio = document.querySelectorAll(".radio");
    botonesRadio.forEach((botonRadio) => {
        botonRadio.addEventListener("click", () => {
            validarTestCompleto();
        });
    });
};

btnEnviarTest.disabled = true;

/*============  End of Validar Test  =============*/

/*=============================================
=                 Enviar Datos                =
=============================================*/

respuestasCorrectas = [];

obtenerRespuestasCorrectas = () => {
    let botonesRadio = document.querySelectorAll(".radio");

    for (let i = 0; i < botonesRadio.length; i++) {
        if (botonesRadio[i].checked === true) {
            respuestasCorrectas.push(
                botonesRadio[i].nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML
            );
            console.log(respuestasCorrectas);
        }
    }
};

/* End of Subsection
-------------------------------------------------- */

valorNombrePreguntas = [];

obtenerNombrePreguntas = () => {
    let nombrePregunta = document.querySelectorAll(".textoPregunta");

    for (let i = 0; i < nombrePregunta.length; i++) {
        valorNombrePreguntas.push(nombrePregunta[i].value);
        console.log(valorNombrePreguntas);
    }
};

/* End of Subsection
-------------------------------------------------- */

btnEnviarTest.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let nombreDelTest = nombreTest.value;
    let temarioAlQuePertenece = valueSelect;

    obtenerRespuestasCorrectas();
    obtenerNombrePreguntas();

    let enviarTest = new FormData();
    enviarTest.append("nombreDelTest", nombreDelTest);
    enviarTest.append("temarioAlQuePertenece", temarioAlQuePertenece);
    enviarTest.append(
        "valorNombrePreguntas",
        JSON.stringify(valorNombrePreguntas)
    );
    enviarTest.append(
        "respuestasCorrectas",
        JSON.stringify(respuestasCorrectas)
    );

    console.log(`respuestas correctas ${respuestasCorrectas}`);

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/src/admin/test/subirTest.php", true);

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            console.log("exito");
        }
    };

    xhr.send(enviarTest);
});

/*============  End of Enviar Datos  =============*/

/*=============================================
=             Eliminar Pregunta               =
=============================================*/

eliminarPregunta = (numVistaPrevia) => {
    console.log("click");
    let vistaPrevias = document.querySelectorAll(".vistaPrevia");

    numVistaPrevia = numVistaPrevia;
    for (let i = 0; i < vistaPrevias.length; i++) {
        if (vistaPrevias[i].getAttribute("numVistaPrevia") === numVistaPrevia) {
            vistaPrevias[i].remove();
            numID--;
            validarTestCompleto();
        }
    }
};

botonesEliminarPregunta = () => {
    let eliminarPreguntaBtn = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".eliminarPregunta__botón"
    );
    eliminarPreguntaBtn.forEach((elemento) => {
        elemento.addEventListener("click", () => {
            numVistaPrevia = elemento.getAttribute("numVistaPrevia");
            eliminarPregunta(numVistaPrevia);
            console.log(numVistaPrevia);
        });
    });
};

botonesEliminarPregunta();

/*============  End of Eliminar Pregunta  =============*/

/*=============================================
=             Eliminar Respuesta              =
=============================================*/

eliminarRespuesta = (numRespuesta) => {
    console.log("click");
    let elementosRadio = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".vistaPrevia__respuestas__radio__elemento"
    );

    numRespuesta = numRespuesta;
    for (let i = 0; i < elementosRadio.length; i++) {
        if (elementosRadio[i].getAttribute("numrespuesta") === numRespuesta) {
            elementosRadio[i].remove();
            validarTestCompleto();
        }
    }
};

botonesEliminarRespuesta = () => {
    let eliminarRespuestaBtn = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".eliminarRespuesta__botón"
    );
    eliminarRespuestaBtn.forEach((elemento) => {
        elemento.addEventListener("click", () => {
            numRespuesta = elemento.getAttribute("numrespuesta");
            eliminarRespuesta(numRespuesta);
            console.log(numRespuesta);
        });
    });
};

/*============  End of Eliminar Respuesta  =============*/
```

La sección de la función para añadir preguntas es donde tengo el problema, el resto de funciones se ejecutan según lo esperado. Agradezco cualquier ayuda o sugerencia.

Si alguien conoce cómo ejecutar una función en elementos existentes y creados dinámicamente sin que me de ese error mencionado antes le agradezco.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo la respuesta. Encontré un método en [este artículo](https://osmancea.medium.com/delegaci%C3%B3n-de-eventos-del-dom-con-javascript-d28131d43686) donde contiene un enlace a [esta página](https://codesandbox.io/s/jnn1powmvv?file=/src/index.js). En resumen, la respuesta está en estas líneas de código, aparte de algunos cambios que realicé en el código:

```
function on(eventName, selector, handler) {
    document.addEventListener(
        eventName,
        function (event) {
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            const path = event.composedPath();
            path.forEach(function (node) {
                elements.forEach(function (elem) {
                    if (node === elem) {
                        handler.call(elem, event);
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        true
    );
}

on("click", ".btnAñadir", function () {
    console.log("hola");
    indice = this.getAttribute("numvistaprevia") - 1;
    añadiendoRespuesta(indice);
});
```

Ahora bien, si alguien me puede aclarar por qué no funciona al usar el estilo de funciones de EcmaScript y cómo es que funciona se lo agradezco.

Comment: En vez de publicar esto como respuesta, deberías agregarlo en la pregunta, porque no soluciona el problema.

Comment: @Triby si es la solución que buscaba, simplemente pregunté por el funcionamiento de la implementación, mi objetivo era ejecutar una función dado un botón existente o creado dinámicamente y lo conseguí en parte gracias a esas líneas de código, digo en parte porque no mostré el código JS completo con todos los cambios pero sí que solucioné mi problema.

Comment: Ok. No sé a qué te refieres con _"estilo de funciones EcmaScript"_, probablemente quieres usar funciones flecha y, si es el caso, solo deberías dejar de usar `this` y recibir los parámetros en la función que asignas al evento.